# Valgrind and LD_PRELOAD - object cannot be preloaded

Tags: linux, valgrind, ld

I am attempting to run my program, which requires a library to be in the
`LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, with valgrind. When I do this I get the
following error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/path/to/lib/libLIBRARY.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot
be preloaded: ignored.
```

However, if I am to run the program **WITHOUT** valgrind, it happily uses the
`LD_PRELOAD`ed library.

Why is this the case? And is there a way to fix it?

(P.S. The system is 64-bit scientific linux 5, I believe)

Comment: I got the same problem when following this simple tutorial http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23 . I'm also 64bit. Everything (example jmaloc and hello app I compile myself, so it is 64bit -> checked with "file")

Comment: Any resolution?  Got this problem myself..

Comment: Look at environment variable [`LD_DEBUG`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).  Specifically try `export LD_DEBUG=all`.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if valgrind is 64-bit, and both the shared library and the application are 32-bit. valgrind itself can't load the library, but it should load for the application itself.

Edit: Oh, and ... you really shouldn't be using LD_PRELOAD for required libraries for your own programs, only for debugging or otherwise overriding libraries. Instead, embed an rpath/runpath in the executable.

Comment: valgrind misses a lot of symbols after you've dlclose'd a shared object, so this is the only good workaround for it. But unfortunatelly doesn't work with 64 bit valgrind as we see

Comment: @newhouse Huh? And `dlclose` is a bad idea in general, but I don't see how that's relevant here.